# Python output print problem for palindrome permutation

Tags: python, algorithm, debugging, data-structures

I want to see if a given string is a permutation of a palindrome or not. Here is the python solution. I am trying to test it for the following input example but I am getting error.

```
import re
class Solution(object):
    def isPalindrome(self, s):

        regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
        s=regex.sub('', lower(s))
        print(s)
        j=len(s)-1
        for i in range(0,len(s)/2):
            if s[i]==s[j]:
                j-=1
            else:
                return False

        return True

    # The word is civic , which is a palindrome. So it should return true.    
    s = "vicic"

print(isPalindrome(s))
```

I get this error : "NameError: name 'self' is not defined". How can I fix it and print the output?

Answer (score 0):

`isPalindrome()` as you have defined it here is associated with the object/class `Solution`.

Unlike a regular Python function your method is called on your solution object.

If you want to call it given your current structure you must first instantiate an instance of solution, create the string you want to test, and then call the method on the object:

```
sol = Solution() # instance of Solution
s = "vicic"
sol.isPalindrome(s) # False
```

Also note that I took your string `s` out from where you had previously declared it as it was in the wrong scope.

In general it seems like your solution class may be a bit of overkill, part of the beauty of Python is its ability to write simple scripts, so you could rewrite `isPalindrome()` as a plain function and not a method.